# Does perl cache regex generation?

Tags: perl

Suppose I have a function that dynamically generates regular expressions and then matches against them.

For example, in the following function `match_here` a `\G` anchor is inserted at the beginning of the regex. This simplifies the API because the caller does not need to remember to include the `pos` anchor in the pattern.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;
use Data::Dumper;

sub match_here {
  my ($str, $index, $rg) = @_;
  pos($str) = $index;
  croak "index ($index) out of bounds" unless pos($str) == $index;
  my $out;
  if ($str =~ /\G$rg/) {
    $out = $+[0]; 
  }
  return $out;
}

# no match starting at position 0
# prints '$VAR1 = undef;'    
print Dumper(match_here("abc", 0, "b+"));
# match from 1 to 2
# prints '$VAR1 = 2;'
print Dumper(match_here("abc", 1, "b+"));
```

I'm wondering whether an anonymous regex object is "compiled" every time the function is evaluated or if there's some caching so that identical strings will not cause additional regex objects to be compiled.

Also, assuming that no caching is done by the Perl interpreter, is compiling a regex object expensive enough to be worth caching (possibly in an XS extension)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From **perlop**(1), under the `m//` operator:

> PATTERN may contain variables, which will be interpolated every time the pattern search is evaluated
>
> [...]
>
> Perl will not recompile the pattern unless an interpolated variable that it contains changes.  You can force Perl to skip the test and never recompile by adding a "/o" (which stands for "once") after the trailing delimiter.  Once upon a time, Perl would recompile regular expressions unnecessarily, and this modifier was useful to tell it not to do so, in the interests of speed.

So yes, there is a cache, and you can even force the use of the cache even when it's invalid by saying `/o`, but you really shouldn't do that.

But that cache only stores one compiled regexp per instance of the `m//` or `s///` operator, so it only helps if the regexp is used with the same variables (e.g. your `$rg`) many times *consecutively*. If you alternate between calling it with `$rg='b+'` and `$rg='c+'` you will get a recompile every time.

For that kind of situation, you can do your own caching with the `qr//` operator. It explicitly compiles the regexp and returns an object that you can store and use to execute the regexp later. That could be incorporated into your `match_here` like this:

```
use feature 'state';

sub match_here {
  my ($str, $index, $rg) = @_;
  pos($str) = $index;
  croak "index ($index) out of bounds" unless pos($str) == $index;
  my $out;
  state %rg_cache;
  my $crg = $rg_cache{$rg} ||= qr/\G$rg/;
  if ($str =~ /$crg/) {
    $out = $+[0]; 
  }
  return $out;
}
```

To add more detail on the basic cache (when not using `qr//`): the fact that `$rg` is a newly allocated lexical variable each time makes no difference. It only matters that the *value* is the same as the previous one.

Here's an example to prove the point:

```
use re qw(Debug COMPILE);

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  # Insane interpolation. Do not use anything remotely like this in real code
  print "MATCHED: $_\n" if /^${\(`cat refile`)}/;
}
```

Every time the match operator executes, it reads `refile`. The regular expression is `^` followed by the contents of `refile`. The debugging output shows that it is recompiled only if the contents of the file have changed. If the file still has the same contents as the last time, the operator notices that the same *string* is being passed to the regexp compiler again, and reuses the cached result.

Or try this less dramatic example:

```
use re qw(Debug COMPILE);

@patterns = (
  '\d{3}',
  '\d{3}',
  '[aeiou]',
  '[aeiou]',
  '\d{3}',
  '\d{3}'
);

for ('xyz', '123', 'other') {
  for $i (0..$#patterns) {
    if(/$patterns[$i]/) {
      print "$_ matches $patterns[$i]\n";
    } else {
      print "$_ does not match $patterns[$i]\n";
    }
  }
}
```

in which there are 18 compilations and 11 of them are cache hits, even though the same "variable" (the same element of the `@patterns` array) is never used twice in a row.

Comment: How does `unless an interpolated variable that it contains changes` interact with lexical variables? Do the `rg`s in separate invocations of the function count as independent or the same variable? I'm not sure how to read it.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet, The interpolation happens unconditionally. If the interpolated pattern is different than the interpolated pattern that was used to compile the regex, it's recompiled.

Comment: Note that interpolating a compiled pattern in another pattern currently causes the compiled pattern to be stringified and recompiled as part of the larger pattern. Only when the pattern consist entirely of a variable (e.g. `/$re/`) is the existing compiled pattern used. This means that passing `qr/b+/` instead of `"b+"` won't help.